# C# Issue regarding a simple tile map for roguelike engine

Tags: c#, console, tile

Alright, first off, this is my first post in here and usually I can get by and simply search for the answer, however, since this is a bit specific, I wasn't able to find an answer to this one.

I'm somewhat of a beginner at coding (I know the basics mostly and have watched many videos and read a lot of tutorials on C#) and am trying to code a ASCII console "game". Everything was going pretty well for a while but now I'm stuck on the mapping part. At first, I thought I'd enter all the coordinates manually for the walls. However I found a post here explaining that a more Object Oriented way of doing it would be to create a Tile class like so.

```
public class Tile
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
    public bool IsWall { get; set; }
}
```

and then populate the list by doing this

```
private static void PopulateTiles()
    {
        for (int x = 1; x < 159; x++)
            for (int y = 3; y < 45; y++)
                Tiles.Add(new Tile { X = x, Y = y });
    }
```

The reason for the odd starting x and y value is because I restrict the tiles to a certain part of the console, the rest being used for the GUI.

In any case, unless there is a better way (And there must be one, I just don't know what it could be), I'm trying to retrieve only parts of that list to change the ISWALL property to set it to TRUE and then use this

```
    static void DrawObstacles()
    {
        foreach (Tile tile in World.Tiles)
        {
            if (tile.IsWall)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(tile.X, tile.Y);
                Console.Write("#");
            }
        }
    }
```

So far, I tried a couple different solutions but obviously, I ran into problems with each of them (I'm also trying to avoid slowing down the program, if possible, and avoid having another loop with 1000+ iterations).

```
    //Tried this
    private static void SetWalls()
    {
        int[] walls = new int[] { };
        walls += Tiles.GetRange(0, 7); //Fails because I cannot use tiles in an int[]... of course
    }

    //This
    List<Tile> walls = new List<Tile>();
    List<Tile> walls = Tiles.GetRange(0, 7);
    List<Tile> walls = Tiles.GetRange(19, 7; //Doesn't work either but I've no idea why here

    //And finally
    List<Tile> walls = new List<Tile>();
    walls.Add(Tiles[Tiles.GetRange(0, 7)]); //Gives me an error saying that System.Collections.Generic.List<Engine.Tile> cannot be converted to int
```

So right now, I'm a bit lost since i'd really prefer to iterate over the list, rather than entering every coordinates manually in a 2D array... and then iterating over it to "build" the walls.

My question is : Is it possible to retrieve only some parts of a list (like index 0 - 7, 19 - 26, 29, 31, 35 - 46) and then iterate over the main list of tiles to use this new "Index List" to change the ISWALL property of the tiles at those indexes... If that makes sense.

Thanks in advance and feel free to tell me if I made some mistakes in the post.

Comment: I got lost in reading this. What exactly is your Question?

Comment: Basically, I want to be able to iterate over the list of tiles and select only some of them to set their ISWALL property to TRUE. I only need to select a certain range of them, like tile 0 - 7, 19 - 26 and such. If that makes sense

Comment: have you not stored your tiles in a 80x25 format? mimicing the screen output? that would make your life easier.. as I think you're trying to make rooms atm right? (I spent far too much of my life in roguelike games)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by storing the tiles in the 80*25 format but the tile array is actually 158*41 since I changed the size of the console as well. It's (160, 60)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot of unnecessary information, so the question is hard to comprehend. However, it appears you do not want to loop through every game object to simply find a few. This is a problem you have in games, mainly with collision. I am assuming you are constructing this game on the console, so any game engine features are likely not at your disposal.

So, I would suggest that maybe you break your objects up in to lists based on their importance or functioning. Doing this, you would only need to loop through every game object on the startup, and then save yourself from exhausting processing during run time.

For example, you can initialize everything like so:

```
    List<GameObject> GameObjects { get; set; }
    List<GameObject> Walls { get; set; }
    List<GameObject> Items { get; set; }

    public Map()
    {
        PopulateTiles();
        StructureCollections();
    }

    //Small processing loop
    private void DrawObstacles()
    {
        foreach(var wall in Walls)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(tile.X, tile.Y);
            Console.Write("#");
        }
    }

    //Called only on startup
    private  void PopulateTiles()
    {
        for (int x = 1; x < 159; x++)
            for (int y = 3; y < 45; y++)
                GameObjects.Add(new GameObject() { X = x, Y = y });
    }

    //Called only on starup
    private void StructureCollections()
    {
        foreach(GameObject gameObj in GameObjects)
        {
            if (gameObj.IsWall)
                Walls.Add(gameObj);

            if (gameObj.IsItem)
                Items.Add(gameObj);
        }
    }
```

This is not a perfect solution, and all really depends on how you are planning to run your game. But I think it is a good start for an idea.

Update: If you want to find a better way to orchestrate the creation of your game objects, instead of making them all by hand, you can break your objects up into more classes. For example:

```
public class GameObject
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
    public bool IsWall { get; set; }

    public GameObject(int x, int y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

}

public class Wall : GameObject
{
    public Wall(int x, int y) : base(x,y)
    {
        IsWall = true;
    }
}
```

Now in this case, you would only have to call for a new `new Wall(x, y);` which will handle everything it needs to operate as a wall, without requiring more parameters.

UPDATE: Since this is accepted as an answer, I feel obligated to point out this answer is for a small and specific issue. If you are going to have many objects that require their own classes, this is not be the best method(In which "Wall" is it's own class). If we are going to have many more objects, this design will likely lead to class explosion.

Comment: That is exactly what I'd like to do, however, I don't know how to change the property to IsWall (Other than entering them manually with a statement like this : gameObjects.Add(new GameObject(X, Y, true) for every single tiles that is a wall... which won't very dry and will end up taking 100's of lines of codes for each statements.